# Google-app-engine Server: Error 500 on working code - deployment problems. Java code

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, webserver

I have this site, a random little one i just play around on with jsf and primefaces.

I have my own domain connected to it, and hosted it on google-app-engine...

It's been working as a charm right up until now. I have not done anything on the site due to vacation time, and suddenly the site is down? It was working when i deployed the last time, now when i go to my site i get this:

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

- It tells me absolutely nothing, i've tried to re deploy my app, after checking that it worked fine running locally. The first couple of time it just kept on waiting for a verify.. So i stopped it, which led me to learn how to do a rollback as i could not redeploy with the same version number after i stopped it the first time.

I got the rollback fixed, and i now deployed what i know i working code to the app-engine, and still when navigating to my site i get the above error? :S

I'm totally clueless here as the error doesn't really give me anything :S

Anyone have any ideas, i can post code etc. if necessary but something tells me that it is something else seeing that my code runs locally, and ran fine deployed too :S

Comment: Look at your logs; the 500 page displayed to end users is completely useless for debugging.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe this is a stupid question, but where do i find those?
Is it thos audit logs in the Admins page?

Comment: On the left side of the Dashboard, Main > Logs, or go to https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=yourappname

Comment: Neither of those to work!

On my dashboard i do not have anything like that :S

And when trying to use the link i just gets redirected to the create new app site - and yes i modified the app name correctly :S

Answer (score 2):

You can find the log file for your web application at

https://appengine.google.com/logs?&app_id=yourappname

or on the Dashboard page in the list on the left side.

---

If you deploy a new version, also re-start the browser to clear old session data. 
(Maybe you still get the 500 error still because of old session data).

Comment: When i go to that link i get to the create new applikation page, even though im logged in, looks like i can't find my app like that? :S